# I'm having an issue with my java checkers game. Pieces do not draw over buttons

Tags: button

The issue is that when I draw the board (each square is a button), then draw the pieces, the pieces do not show up.

I tried to use ZOrder but it doesn't work, we also tried layeredpane earlier on. Can someone help me out with this?

Before, I had just made the squares drawn squares. I was thinking of making the pieces buttons but realized that wouldn't work as I need to press the square unto which the piece goes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class checkers extends JPanel {

    private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int CELL_SIZE = 60;

    private static final Color WHITE = new Color(255, 206, 158);
    private static final Color BROWN = new Color(209, 139, 71);
    private static final Color BLACK_PIECE = new Color(128, 128, 128);
    private static final Color RED_PIECE = new Color(255, 0, 0);

    private static final int[][] piecePlacement = {
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0},
            {0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1},
            {-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0}
    };

    public checkers() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE));
        createButtons();
    }

    private void createButtons() {
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                button.setOpaque(true);
                button.setBorderPainted(false);
                button.setFocusPainted(false);
                button.setBackground((row + col) % 2 == 0 ? WHITE : BROWN);
                button.addActionListener(new ClickedButtonListener());
                add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ClickedButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("button");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Set the z-order of the buttons to be below the drawn pieces
        for (Component component : getComponents()) {
            if (component instanceof JButton) {
                setComponentZOrder(component, 0);
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                int x = col * CELL_SIZE;
                int y = row * CELL_SIZE;

                if (piecePlacement[row][col] != 0) {
                    if (piecePlacement[row][col] == 1) {
                        g.setColor(BLACK_PIECE);
                        g.fillOval(x + 10, y + 10, CELL_SIZE - 20, CELL_SIZE - 20);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(RED_PIECE);
                        g.fillOval(x + 10, y + 10, CELL_SIZE - 20, CELL_SIZE - 20);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkers Board");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(490, 515);

        checkers checkers = new checkers();
        frame.add(checkers);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```